# How to attach a device tree blob to a linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, device-tree

Is it possible to attach a Device Tree blob (dtbo) to a kernel module, so that when the kernel module is inserted into the kernel the DTS structure is updated with new contents from that module?

I found some articles that mention setting `CONFIG_OF_OVERLAY` and `CONFIG_CONFIGFS` flags when compiling the kernel ([Instructions for Dynamically Loading Device Tree Overlays into Linux Kernel](https://www.96boards.org/documentation/consumer/dragonboard/dragonboard410c/guides/dt-overlays.md.html)), but that doesn't seem to be the whole story.
There's also a tutorial on [yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_dmlwFCBS4) with [code available on github](https://github.com/Johannes4Linux/Linux_Driver_Tutorial/tree/main/26_dt_spi), but again not the whole story, the dts blob is inserted manually.

Comment: `DTS structure is updated with new contents from that module`: Even if you change the DTB during runtime AFAIK you need to reboot the system for new changes in DTB to take take effect and if the LKM gets inserted again it may change the DTB again

Comment: what if the LKM is inserted on boot? I'm working with Yocto and am trying to make developement process easier and less time consuming as every change in the kernel source requires recompilation of the whole kernel. Having both dts and drivers as an external LKM really can speed up things.

Comment: My understanding is that device tree binaries (.dtbs) exist so that one kernel can be pushed out to many hardware devices made by the same vendor.  By having the dtb describe the hardware, then you can have one e.g., NAND Flash driver that works across many hardware variants with slightly different NAND Flash part numbers.  Since the hardware doesn't change, the dtb shouldn't change.  Perhaps you're looking for something else.  Could you describe what your project is trying to achieve?

Comment: Perhaps I was wrong with naming things. What I really mean is to attach a compiled Device Tree structure describing hardware used in a kernel module to that kernel module. This way when the kernel module is loaded the hardware used would be known. I want to omit the need to recompile the kernel source every time the DTS is changed in the development process.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I found some pretty good instructions [here](https://github.com/ikwzm/dtbocfg) about how to set up the DT Overlay Configuration File System and feed your dtbo in at runtime.  Seems like you need a reasonably modern kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the overlays, again it appears that I was wrong with what I asked for in my question. I need to compile a dts overlay file and put that into a kernel module.